# How do I segue to another viewController that shares the same root controller as the current one?

Tags: ios, swift, segue, viewcontroller

I have 3 `viewControllers`: A, B and C.
A has a segue to B and A also has a segue to C.

If I'm currently in C, how do I segue over to B?

> Note; I need to keep A active because once I'm in B, I need to be able
>   to unwind back to A.

The following solution would be nice if I could unwind from C to A and then push to B without showing A in the process, but I can't get this to work, and no-one has provided a solution.

[Chain two segues to look like one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35821305/chain-two-segues-to-look-like-one)

> Note; I'm not using a `UINavigationController`.  I've tried simply
>   pushing from C to B but then I'm not able to deallocate C.   Calling
>   unwind on C at any point during this process gives weird behaviour
>   where A might appear on screen at some point.

Does anyone have a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

There is plenty of way to accomplish what you want.

I would do something really easy: that is to add an **unwind segue** (it's explained above how to add one) to exit to the first A vc, and add a **custom segue** (no matter which one) between B and C (that you simply create with the storyboard).

You start in A, then:

- If you go to B, you can come back using the `self.dismiss`, your using your exit segue.
- If you go to C, you can come back to A the same way, or you can go to B.
- Once you are in B (from: A to C, C to B), you can come back to C using `self.dismiss` or you can come back to A using the exit segue.

To add un unwind segue, you must add a function to your first VC of the type:

```
@IBAction func unwindToA(segue: UIStoryboardSegue)
```

Then, in the storyboard when you are creating your segue on the your B view controller (using control+drag), start to drag from the VC icon (on the top of the screen) to the exit icon. Then, you will see appear a new segue, named 'unwindToA', which will take you back to your first VC: A.

[image: You can see theses icons here (on the top of the screen)]

To create your segue from B to C, you can do by control+drag from the first to the second VC in your storyboard, and choose the type you prefer (or you can create a custom segue if those provided don't correspond to want you expect).

Comment: Let me clarify - I already have unwind segues from `viewController B` to `viewController A` and from `viewController C` to `viewController A`.   When I go from A to C, B has not been instantiated - hence I would not be able to segue back to it if I created an unwind relationship for C to B.  If I do create a push segue from C to B, B is then not unwinding to A (like it should).  It is unwinding to C again.  What I need is to Go from B to C and then I believe I need to somehow call dismiss on B to have it de-allocated.